# COM SURROGATE to 30% cpu

Tags: windows, filesystems

I have recently been adding features that use the file system. I've done something that causes the COM SURROGATE to eat up an entire core and leaving `file explorer` is a "spinning wheel of death" kind of state.

Eventually I'll realize which code path is bad, and post back in. It doesn't actually reproduce every time. But maybe someone already understands this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I know what's happening.

I'm creating folders in `Documents/MyApp` each time the app is run, generating a unique name from the name of the current date. In these files I am writing at least one file. This resulted in a lot of folders and files.

Some of these files where produced during development and are probably corrupted.

When I navigate to `Documents/MyApp`, file explorer breaks trying to index this folder for what ever reason.